# How to get access_log summary by goaccess starting from certain date?

Tags: bash, apache, centos, goaccess

Currently I keep 6 weeks of apache access_log. If I generate a access summary at month end:

```
cat /var/log/httpd/access_log* | goaccess --output-format=csv
```

the summary will include some access data from previous month.

How can I skip logs of previous month and summarise from first day of month?

p.s. the data-format is: `%d/%b/%Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trade the Useless Use of `cat` for a useful `grep`.

```
grep -n $(date +'[0-3][0-9]/%b/%Y') /var/log/httpd/access_log* |
goaccess --output-format=csv
```

If the logs are by date, it would be a lot more economical to skip the logs which you know are too old or too new, i.e. modify the wildcard argument so you only match the files you really want (or run something like `find -mtime -30` to at least narrow the set to a few files).

(The `cat` is useless because, if `goaccess` is at all correctly written, it should be able to handle

```
goaccess --output-format=csv /var/log/httpd/access_log*
```

just fine.)

Comment: `grep --no-filename $(date +"[0-3][1-9]/%b/%Y")` (the `--no-filename` is needed for goaccess)

Comment: @ohho Duh, I tried to remind myself but forgot anyway! Thanks for the note -- updated.

Comment: From the man page, this should work too: `zcat -f access.log* | sed -n '/'\`date +"01\/%b\/%Y"\`'/,$ p' | goaccess --output-format=csv`

Comment: @Kayla This works poorly if `access.log.0.Z` is the newest -- this is a situation where the wildcard expansion will produce the files in completely the wrong order.

Comment: BTW, should `[0-3][1-9]` be `[0-3][0-9]`?